# Obtain a private URL to a file in iCloud Drive without making the file available to anyone with the link

Tags: icloud, finder, url

I would like to get links to files in my iCloud Drive so that I can paste links to them in other apps (notes, email, etc) for quick access to these files in the future. I know that I can share the files and make them available to anyone with the link, but I don’t want anyone but me to be able to see these files — I want to make it impossible for anyone who can’t log in to iCloud as me to see these files, even if they obtain the URL.

Is it possible in Finder to get a URL to a file that only works for me and no one else? If I try to share the file and select “Only people you can invite can make changes”, then I *have* to share the link with someone before it will let me copy the link.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing good except for the last line where you will *have* to share the link with someone.

Share the link with yourself.

Choose imessages as the sharing option and enter your email or number. And add yourself.

To check the validity, [This](https://www.icloud.com/pages/0uJfpqtOJ4mqF9duzb7tuVJcQ#Serif_Newsletter) is a .Pages file and please try to access it and tell me if you can open and edit it or not.

Since this requires sign-in, I don't think you will be allowed to edit or even view it.

Only bad thing is the file name is in the URL

Comment: If I add my iCloud email as a recipient, the Share button gets grayed out. It only accepts emails of people who aren’t me.

Comment: @ballpointben use a different email address you own then for sharing :-)

Comment: I just sent myself an iMessage from my mac with the link I put in the answer.

Comment: Please check the link in the answer and tell m me if you can access the document.